# Firebase Database connection failed because invalid authentication credentials

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase Database in Android for showing my users they're status, when my service start it connect to the db and listen for changes and work's well at the beginning, after phone restart or a period of time I get the log error as described below and there is no connection to the DB. I encounter this problem when testing on S7, in S5 I did not encounter this problem.
I saw that for this error the solution is to replace FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getFirebaseUser() with a listener FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener, and it did not helped solve the problem.

Error:

> PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Provided authentication credentials are
>   invalid. This usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not
>   initialized correctly. Make sure your google-services.json file has
>   the correct firebase_url and api_key. You can re-download
>   google-services.json from https://console.firebase.google.com/.

Thanks

```
public void listenToDbChanges() {
    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "Auth");
            listenToDbChangesStart(firebaseAuth);
        }
    };
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener = null;

/**
 * Called when FirebaseUser listener had return the user
 */
private void listenToDbChangesStart(FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
    if (firebaseAuth == null) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "firebaseAuth is null ignore");
        return;
    }
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    if (isListeningToDb) {
        Logger.d(TAG, "Already listening to db");
        return;
    }
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    DatabaseReference userRef = null;
    if (firebaseUser != null) {

        String path = getPathOfDB(firebaseUser);
        Logger.d(TAG,"Path is:"+path);
        userRef = database.getReference(path);

        if (userRef != null) {
            userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Logger.d(TAG, "onDataChange");
                    // READ
                    }
          }
  }
```

Comment: are you enabled social login in console in authentication menu ?

Comment: add your service code please

Comment: Seems that deleting all Google Play services storage solve the problem... **Settings => Apps => Google Play services => Storage => MANAGE STORAGE => CLEAR ALL DATA**, this issue probably need to be fix by Firebase or Google.